# Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an initializer or method in

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I update my project from `Swift2.2` to `Swift3.0` But `"Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an initializer or method"` issue received.

Here is code **:**

```
for object in Students {
    let sectionNumber = collation.section(for: object.firstName!, collationStringSelector: #selector(NSObjectProtocol.self))
    sections[sections.count - 1 - sectionNumber].append(object)
}
```

[image]

Comment: `#selector(NSObjectProtocol.self)` should return a String.

Comment: Ok So how resolve it?

Comment: `NSObjectProtocol.self`, `.self` is type, not an initialiser or method. `.init.` or `.someMethod` would be fine.

Comment: btw `#selector()` is the only valid syntax in swift3 instead of `String`.

Comment: as user2215977 pointed out, #selector() needs to have a method not type.

Comment: Have you solve your problem?

Comment: Type 'NSObjectProtocol' has no member 'init' '

Comment: how i resolve it?

Comment: why you decrease my repotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Person: NSObject {
    @objc var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

let p = Person(name: "Alice")

let collation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.current()
collation.section(for: p, collationStringSelector: #selector(getter: Person.name))
```

This is also fine since `Selector` is from Objective-C. Which we need to `:NSObject` and `@objc`.

Comment: how to implement this in my scenario?

Comment: I would be great to have a look on your Person class/struct.

Comment: consider marking the answer as correct, if it helps. =]

Answer (score 0):

As per docs

```
func section(for object: Any, collationStringSelector selector: selector) -> Int

Description 
Returns an integer identifying the section in which a model object belongs.
The table-view controller should iterate through all model objects for the table view and call this method for each object. If the application provides a Localizable.strings file for the current language preference, the indexed-collation object localizes each string returned by the method identified by selector. It uses this localized name when collating titles. The controller should use the returned integer to identify a local “section” array in which it should insert object.

Parameters  
object
A model object of the application that is part of the data model for the table view.

*selector*
A selector that identifies a method returning an identifying string for object that is used in collation. The method should take no arguments and return an NSString object. For example, this could be a name property on the object.

Returns 
An integer that identifies the section in which the model object belongs. The numbers returned indicate a sequential ordering.
```

**Solution**

Change like below

```
collation.section(for: "test", collationStringSelector: #selector(getStr)) //here getStr is an other function returning String



func getStr()->String{
        return "test"; // this should return an identifying string for object that is used in your collation
}
```

Comment: how to implement this in my scenario?

Comment: @Mian Shahbaz Akram can you show your Students class?

Answer (score 0):

I implement user2215977 answer but app crash again & again. Now i just change the #selector(NSObjectProtocol.self) to "self". All error gone but just one warning received " Use of string literal for Objective-C selectors is deprecated; use #selector instead ".

If any person have idea to resolve this warning then share me.Otherwise error go now.